# Reduce Spacing between UILabel ( Vertical Position ambiguous )

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilabel

I have below two UILabels , Which has below constraints

```
self.topText.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 15),
        self.topText.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            self.topText.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -screenWidth/2),

self.bottomText.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: self.TopText.bottomAnchor, constant: 5),
            self.bottomText.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.TopText.leadingAnchor),
            self.bottomText.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topText.trailingAnchor),
```

And screenshot looks like below, I am unable to reduce the spacing between these. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Do you have the bottomAnchor constraint set for the bottom label? It seems you have it set in the screenshot but it's not in the your code above

Comment: I have added a bottom constraint , still no luck.